# Show that $\mathsf T(\vec x)$ = $\mathsf L(\vec x)$, for all vectors $\vec x$ in $\Bbb R^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing, linear-transformations

Consider two linear transformations $\mathsf T$ and $\mathsf L$ from $\Bbb R^2$ to $\Bbb R^2$. We are told that $\mathsf T(\vec v_1)$ = $\mathsf L(\vec v_1)$ and $\mathsf T(\vec v_2)$ = $\mathsf L(\vec v_2)$ for the vectors $\vec v_1$ and $\vec v_2$ sketched below. Show that $\mathsf T(\vec x)$ = $\mathsf L(\vec x)$, for all vectors $\vec x$ in $\Bbb R^2$.

Can I prove this by stating that $\mathsf L$ is the inverse of $\mathsf T$?[image]

Comment: I can't see any logic stating that L is the inverse of T. They are the same. Try proving that $v_{1}$, $v_{2}$ are a basis of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$

Comment: How would I go about showing this?

Comment: It depends on the information you have. If you just have the sketch then the proof should be telling how would be the sketch of two linearly dependent vectors. If you have the vectors coordinates, then you cand do it by computing the determinant of its matrix, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any vector $x$, one can find $a_1$ and $a_2$ such that:
$$x = a_1v_1 + a_2v_2.$$
This is true since it is obvious from the picture that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent.

Now, we know that:
$$T(x) = T(a_1v_1 + a_2v_2)$$
Using the properties of a linear transformation, we have that:

$$T(x) = a_1T(v_1) + a_2T(v_2)$$

Since $T(v_1) = L(v_1)$ and $T(v_2) = L(v_2)$, then:

$$T(x) = a_1L(v_1) + a_2L(v_2) = L(a_1v_1 + a_2v_2) = L(x) ~\square$$

Answer (score 0):

An attempt at my first "proof" for linear algebra

I'm going to assume that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent (maybe obvious from the picture). We have:
$$T(v_1) = L(\vec{v_1}), T(\vec{v_2}) = L(\vec{v_2})$$ For set $\{\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}\}$ s.t. $span\{\vec{v_1}, \vec{v_2}\} = \mathbb{R}^2$. $$T(\vec{x}) = T(a_1\vec{v_1} + a_2\vec{v_2})$$
And for $L$
$$L(\vec{x}) = L(a_1\vec{v_1} + a_2\vec{v_2})$$
By uniqueness of linear combination and linearity we know that are equal.

Comment: To tag on, we should even write the following: $T(x)=T(a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2) = a_1 T(v_1) + a_2 T (v_2) =a_1 L(v_1) + a_2 L (v_2) = L(a_1 v_1 + a_2 v_2)= L(x)$.